# How to use an iron-ajax response on another page, in Polymer?

Tags: javascript, polymer

How do I pass the response of an iron-ajax to another page?

I have two pages which will display different things from the same `data(response)`. Is there a way to pass the response of an iron-ajax in `page-x.html` to `page-y.html` without generating the same request in each page.

Comment: Which Polymer version?

Comment: I didn't include the version number because we are in the process of updating it to 3.0. HakanC's solution works in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here the very simple code to pass the `iron-ajax` 's response to two or more page (element- components); And if you have a specific requirement then re-issue your question in order to make more specific answer.:

```
<iron-ajax 
         auto
         id="request"
         url="your url here "
         last-response="{{response}}"
> </iron-ajax>
<page-x x-data = "{{response}}"></page-x>
<page-y y-data = "{{response}}"></page-y>
```

at `page-x` you will have a `xData` and at `page-y` you will have `yData` property with received data from `iron-ajax`

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm.